# Need Help Converting This Pinescript into V5 TradingView

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

So I have an old pinescript I believe v2 or v3 that I Need help converting into V5 as my knowledge of pinescript is very limited, but I can not do that auto convert to work because the values seem to be not converting or it has changed so much. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    study(title="MA", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true)
    src=close
    l =input(6, title="VMA Length") 
    std=input(false, title="Show Trend Direction")
    bc=input(false, title="Color bars based on Trend")
    k = 1.0/l
    pdm = max((src - src[1]), 0)
    mdm = max((src[1] - src), 0)
    pdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdmS[1]) + k*pdm)
    mdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(mdmS[1]) + k*mdm)
    s = pdmS + mdmS
    pdi = pdmS/s
    mdi = mdmS/s
    pdiS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdiS[1]) + k*pdi)
    mdiS = ((1 - k)*nz(mdiS[1]) + k*mdi)
    d = abs(pdiS - mdiS)
    s1 = pdiS + mdiS
    iS = ((1 - k)*nz(iS[1]) + k*d/s1)
    hhv = highest(iS, l) 
    llv = lowest(iS, l) 
    d1 = hhv - llv
    vI = (iS - llv)/d1
    vma = (1 - k*vI)*nz(vma[1]) + k*vI*src
    vmaC=(vma > vma[1]) ? green : (vma<vma[1]) ? red : (vma==vma[1]) ? blue : black 
    plot(vma, color=std?vmaC:black, linewidth=3, title="VMA")
    barcolor(bc?vmaC:na)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript v5, you must declare you variable before calling it.
So :

```
pdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdmS[1]) + k*pdm)
```

doesn't work anymore, because you try to acces pdmS[1] before declaring it.
Use 'var' to declare a variable with a value used only one the frst loop over your code.

Here is your code in v5 :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='MA', shorttitle='MA', overlay=true)
src = close
l = input(6, title='VMA Length')
std = input(false, title='Show Trend Direction')
bc = input(false, title='Color bars based on Trend')
k = 1.0 / l
pdm = math.max(src - src[1], 0)
mdm = math.max(src[1] - src, 0)
var pdmS = 0.0
pdmS := (1 - k) * nz(pdmS[1]) + k * pdm
var mdmS = 0.0
mdmS := (1 - k) * nz(mdmS[1]) + k * mdm
s = pdmS + mdmS
pdi = pdmS / s
mdi = mdmS / s
var pdiS = 0.0
pdiS := (1 - k) * nz(pdiS[1]) + k * pdi
var mdiS = 0.0
mdiS := (1 - k) * nz(mdiS[1]) + k * mdi
d = math.abs(pdiS - mdiS)
s1 = pdiS + mdiS
var iS = 0.0
iS := (1 - k) * nz(iS[1]) + k * d / s1
hhv = ta.highest(iS, l)
llv = ta.lowest(iS, l)
d1 = hhv - llv
vI = (iS - llv) / d1
var vma = 0.0
vma := (1 - k * vI) * nz(vma[1]) + k * vI * src
vmaC = vma > vma[1] ? color.green : vma < vma[1] ? color.red : vma == vma[1] ? color.blue : color.black
plot(vma, color=std ? vmaC : color.black, linewidth=3, title='VMA')
barcolor(bc ? vmaC : na)
```